# How to use encrypted password in WSS4J Spring Security

Tags: java, encryption, spring-ws

I am using Spring WS Security through WSS4JSecurityInterceptor. Howvever, while validating signature I need to read keystore passwords.

The keystore passwords will be encrypted. Can you please let me know how to decrypt it before validating the signature?

My configuration is as below:

```
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="Signature"/>
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
            <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/keystore.jks"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signature Using Spring - Ws WSS4JSecurityInterceptor

Generated Keytool using:

```
keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keypass kpi135 -keystore akulastore.jks -storepass ab987c
```

Generate Certificate for Keytool:

```
keytool -certreq -alias signFiles -keystore akulastore.jks -file cert.csr
```

Place the Keytool, Certificate on the client side.

Place Keytool on the server side

And made the configurations as :

```
Server Side Interceptor

<bean id="wsDigCerSecurityInterceptor" 
   class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
<property name="validationActions" value="Signature"/>
<property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
<bean
   class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
<property name="keyStorePassword" value="ab987c"/>
<property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/akulastore.jks"/>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>


Client Side Interceptor

<bean id="wsDigCerSecurityInterceptor"
   class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
<property name="securementActions" value="Signature"/>
<property name="securementUsername" value="signFiles"/>
<property name="securementPassword" value="kpi135"/>
<property name="securementSignatureCrypto">
<bean 
   class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
<property name="keyStorePassword" value="ab987c"/>
<property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/akulastore.jks"/>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
```